# Camera.open() THROWS null

Tags: android, exception, null, android-camera

**Just to be clear: this isn't about a function returning `null`.  It's about a function throwing an `Exception` which turns out to be `null`.**

```
throw null;
```

Like that.

I have a camera application which has been working fine in Ice Cream Sandwich for a while.  In Gingerbread it collapses; however, I have just seen `Camera.open()` **throw** `null`.

```
try {
    releaseCameraAndPreview();
    mCamera = Camera.open(camera);
    //and the above throws ...
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    //and e is null, causing a NullPointerException
}
```

`releaseCameraAndPreview` is this:

```
private void releaseCameraAndPreview() {
    if (mCamera != null) {
        mCamera.stopPreview();
        mCamera.release();
        mCamera = null;
    }
}
```

The camera is null at this point so nothing happens.

I didn't even know it was *possible* to throw null.  What does it mean?

Comment: releaseCameraAndPreview(); check what is happening in this function. Also post the full stacktrace

Comment: post stacktrace anyway.

Comment: use mCamera.release(); after done picture

Comment: According to the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#open%28%29), if the device does not have a back-facing camera, `Camera.open()` returns null. You sure you are using open(int) and not open()?

Comment: By the way, you know there won't be a stacktrace, right?  The Exception is null so printStackTrace() is throwing a NPE.

Comment: @verybadalloc It **THROWS** null.  I am 100% sure I am using `open(int)`

Answer (score 0):

Restarting the phone fixed this; I can only assume the camera got into a corrupted state somehow during testing.

Comment: but this is not a best solution for this.

Comment: I know, but I can't work out why `Camera.open()` would throw `null` either.

Answer (score 0):

> Re-locks the camera to prevent other processes from accessing it. Camera objects are locked by default unless unlock() is called. Normally reconnect() is used instead.
>   Since API level 14, camera is automatically locked for applications in start(). Applications can use the camera (ex: zoom) after recording starts. There is no need to call this after recording starts or stops.

Check if object is locked and try unlocking it if so.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#lock%28%29